# Need Japanese IME with Dvorak keyboard with 13.10

Tags: japanese, dvorak

I recently did a fresh install of 13.10 and enabled Japanese language support.

In the past this seemed to work seamlessly with my other keyboard settings when I set up my Dvorak keyboard.

But this time when I toggle the IME on it uses the standard QWERTY layout.  Typing English uses the Dvorak layout as I expect.

This just worked for me in the past to the point where I stopped paying attention to what the underlying IME is and I don't recall any special steps other then choosing my keyboard layout and enabling Japanese.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I fixed my problem:

I looked in `/usr/bin` for all ibus related programs (ls `/usr/bin/ibus*`).

I saw "ibus-setup" and ran it.

In the 詳細 tab under キーボードレイアウト I checked システムキーボードレイアウトを使用する。

(Did I mention I installed Ubuntu localized for Japanese?)

There's nothing in the system settings that brings up this dialog, is it hidden somewhere or am I just missing something?

Comment: I can't find an option that let's me mark it as accepted, is it possible that I can't mark my own answers as accepted?

Comment: You can do it by clicking the tick under the count of votes, see the picture on http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217657.